# Access contacts split by their account?

Tags: ios, swift, contacts, contacts-framework

I've been trying to figure out how to pull contacts with the Contacts Framework, but split them up by which account they come from such as Google, Facebook, iCloud, etc..

I've seen apps like Contacts Sync for Gmail and Simpler Contacts have done this, but I'm unaware of how to gain access to the accounts on the phone.

Any help is appreciated.